# Speakeasy express js:onetime password generation is not expired

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, one-time-password

Here is my implementation for one time OTP(expire after one minute) with speakeasy package

```
 var secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({length: 20}).base32;
        var token = speakeasy.totp({
            secret: secret,
            encoding: 'base32',
            time:60
        });
  console.log('OTP',token);
```

verify token

```
var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
            secret: req.params.secret,
            encoding: 'base32',
            token: req.params.token,
            time:60
        });
```

but the OTP is never expired it `console.log(verified)`  always returns true after the expiry time

Answer (score 0):

In your token definition:

```
var token = speakeasy.totp({
            secret: secret,
            encoding: 'base32',
            time:60
        });
```

Change the `time` option to `step` option and try again:

```
var token = speakeasy.totp({
            secret: secret,
            encoding: 'base32',
            step:300  //time in seconds
        });
```

There are two options you can use: [time](https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy#getting-a-time-based-token-for-a-custom-time) and [step](https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy#verifying-a-token-and-calculating-a-delta)?

Please check out both the options and decide which one is appropriate in your case. If `time` is the right option for you then you must specify epoch time in seconds. `60` doesn't seem to be a right value here. A valid value for `time` could be `1495176700`.

Give epoch time after which you want your token to be expired and then try again. Hope it will work with these changes.

Comment: As per the documentation time is spefied in seconds   from their doc  `var token = speakeasy.totp({
  secret: secret.base32,
  encoding: 'base32',
  time: 1453667708 // specified in seconds 
});`

Comment: i didn't get the meaning of this "60 doesn't seem to be a right value here. A valid value for time could be 1495176700"

Comment: Also where can i add the epcoh time??

Comment: I want  to expire the token after sometime thats why i am choose the time based counter

Comment: Please check the hyperlinks I have mentioned for `time` and `step`. Then you will get the idea.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it

Comment: I just want to expire the OTP after 5 minutes

Comment: I have edited the answer, check it out. And please read the [documentation](https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy) if you still couldn't understand it!